# Game Map Editor - CSS Grid Performance

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have this less than mediocre tool I made to help me design maps for a game I am working on. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/ede0m/GustoMapDesignerTool).

I used CSS grids to build a tile editor for my tile based game map. When you run the app (with init button) as is and start to edit the tiles, it is pretty responsive. But when I scale the map size (using multX and multY fields), the click and drag input and css grid response seems to drag. Note: if you scale the above fields to 10 or so, it will take ~30s to initialize the grid. This lag becomes pretty hindering when trying to design a bigger map.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make CSS grid more responsive with a large number of rows/columns?

Any more appropriate approaches for making a tile editor grid instead of native css grid?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the CSS grid. Have you tried testing in other browsers/systems to see if the problem is with that?

Comment: Wow, thanks! Other browsers seem to work better! Can't believe this didn't occur to me.@YaakovAinspan

Comment: For a minor speed enhancement (and I do mean minor), you could try replacing `var origin = Math.floor(((cols * rows) / 2) - (cols/2));` with `var origin = Math.floor(((cols * rows) * 0.5) - (cols*0.5));`,  - as multiplication is slightly faster than division in javascript.